# SYSLOG-NG - Having trouble with a destination

Tags: syslog, splunk

I'm trying to set up a seperate log file for all windows messages. I've set up a match for MSWinEventLog, but it's completely ignoring my configuration

Here's my config, which is straight after the src object

```
filter f_windows    { match("MSWinEventLog"); };
destination winFIFO { file("/var/log/splunk/syslog-ng/winFIFO"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_windows); destination(winFIFO); flags(final); };
```

It all ends up in this one instead:

```
filter f_messages   { not facility(news, mail) and not filter(f_iptables); };
destination messages { file("/var/log/messages"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_messages); destination(messages); };
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm... here's mine lifted from [gentoo's security handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/security/security-handbook.xml?part=1&chap=3#doc_chap4) w/ some iptables modifications. honestly I don't remember how I wrote it but maybe the term 'value' has some meaning?

```
@version: 3.0                      
#                                  
# /etc/syslog-ng.conf              
#                                  

options {
  stats_freq (0);
  flush_lines (0);
  time_reopen (10);
  log_fifo_size (1000);
  long_hostnames(off); 
  use_dns (no);        
  use_fqdn (no);       
  create_dirs (no);    
  keep_hostname (yes); 
  perm(0640);          
  group("log");        
};                     

source src {
  unix-stream("/dev/log");
  internal();             
  file("/proc/kmsg");     
};                        

destination d_authlog { file("/var/log/auth.log"); };
destination d_syslog { file("/var/log/syslog.log"); };
destination d_cron { file("/var/log/crond.log"); };   
destination d_daemon { file("/var/log/daemon.log"); };
destination d_kernel { file("/var/log/kernel.log"); };
destination d_lpr { file("/var/log/lpr.log"); };      
destination d_user { file("/var/log/user.log"); };    
destination d_uucp { file("/var/log/uucp.log"); };    
destination d_mail { file("/var/log/mail.log"); };    
destination d_news { file("/var/log/news.log"); };    
destination d_ppp { file("/var/log/ppp.log"); };      
destination d_debug { file("/var/log/debug.log"); };  
destination d_messages { file("/var/log/messages.log"); };
destination d_errors { file("/var/log/errors.log"); };    
destination d_everything { file("/var/log/everything.log"); };
destination d_iptables { file("/var/log/iptables.log"); };    
destination d_acpid { file("/var/log/acpid.log"); };          
destination d_console { usertty("root"); };                   

# Log everything to tty12
destination console_all { file("/dev/tty12"); };

filter f_auth { facility(auth); };
filter f_authpriv { facility(auth, authpriv); };
filter f_syslog { program(syslog-ng); };        
filter f_cron { facility(cron); };              
filter f_daemon { facility(daemon); };          
filter f_kernel { facility(kern) and not filter(f_iptables); };
filter f_lpr { facility(lpr); };                               
filter f_mail { facility(mail); };                             
filter f_news { facility(news); };                             
filter f_user { facility(user); };                             
filter f_uucp { facility(cron); };                             
filter f_news { facility(news); };                             
filter f_ppp { facility(local2); };                            
filter f_debug { not facility(auth, authpriv, news, mail); };  
filter f_messages { level(info..warn) and not facility(auth, authpriv, mail, news, cron) and not program(syslog-ng) and not filter(f_iptables); };              
filter f_everything { level(debug..emerg) and not facility(auth, authpriv); };
filter f_emergency { level(emerg); };
filter f_info { level(info); };
filter f_notice { level(notice); };
filter f_warn { level(warn); };
filter f_crit { level(crit); };
filter f_err { level(err); };
filter f_iptables { match("IN=" value("MESSAGE")) and match("OUT=" value("MESSAGE")); };
filter f_acpid { program("acpid"); };

log { source(src); filter(f_acpid); destination(d_acpid); };
log { source(src); filter(f_authpriv); destination(d_authlog); };
log { source(src); filter(f_syslog); destination(d_syslog); };
log { source(src); filter(f_cron); destination(d_cron); };
log { source(src); filter(f_daemon); destination(d_daemon); };
log { source(src); filter(f_kernel); destination(d_kernel); };
log { source(src); filter(f_lpr); destination(d_lpr); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
log { source(src); filter(f_news); destination(d_news); };
log { source(src); filter(f_ppp); destination(d_ppp); };
log { source(src); filter(f_user); destination(d_user); };
log { source(src); filter(f_uucp); destination(d_uucp); };
#log { source(src); filter(f_debug); destination(d_debug); };
log { source(src); filter(f_messages); destination(d_messages); };
log { source(src); filter(f_err); destination(d_errors); };
log { source(src); filter(f_emergency); destination(d_console); };
log { source(src); filter(f_everything); destination(d_everything); };
log { source(src); filter(f_iptables); destination(d_iptables); };

# Log everything to tty12
#log { source(src); destination(console_all); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Syslog had got itself in a bit of a knot. When I stopped the service, it would still be visible when I did a 'ps -ef |grep syslog' - I killed it, and restarted the service anew and it works fine now.